# Enzyme and jest testing a react app that updates state after setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, timeout, jestjs, enzyme

I am using `enzyme` and `jest` to test an app that updates the `state` and `DOM` after a certain time after it's mounted (using `setTimout()`). But, how do I make sure that time has passed and perform the check?

I tried using `jest.advanceTimersByTime()` but it gave me an warning. `Warning: An update to %s inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`
So I did just that but still nothing changes.

```js
const someComponents = () => {
  return (<div className="child"></div>);
}

const App = () => {
  const [remove, setRemove] = useState(false);
  setTimeout(() => setRemove(true), 5000);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { remove &&
         <someComponent/>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

and as for my test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('test', () => {
  it('should remove child at end of timer', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.child')).toHaveLength(1);

    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000000);

      wrapper.update(); //Do I need this?
      console.log(wrapper.debug())// Still shows child in DOM
      expect(wrapper.find('.child')).toHaveLength(0);
    });
  };
}
```

**After 5s `someComponent` should have unmounted but its still there when I try to test it.** Also what is the correct way to access `remove` and `setRemove` with enzyme? There is not a lot of info on using `enzyme` with `react hooks`.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a problem where current testing libraries aren't handling `useEffect` properly (at the moment), so the test will always fail. You can find the currently tracked issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14769).

On a side note, your hook example needs to utilize `useEffect` in order to work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Example = () => <div className="child">child</div>;

const App = () => {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setShowChild(false), 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{showChild && <Example />}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Hook Timer]

---

That said, a workaround is to **use classes** for the time being.

**Here's a local example showcasing the hook issue and a working class example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/hooks-versus-classes

To install:

- open a terminal to your desktop.
- type `git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/hooks-versus-classes.git` and enter.
- type `cd hooks-versus-classes`.
- type `yarn install` or `npm install`.
- type `yarn test` or `npm run test` to run the tests (they'll all pass, but [one](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/hooks-versus-classes/blob/master/src/components/Header/__tests__/Header.test.js#L11-L14) will throw a `console.error` and it's asserted to **not** function properly).
- type `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` to run the project.

Working class code example:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Example = () => <div className="child">child</div>;

class App extends Component {
  state = { showChild: true };

  componentDidMount = () => this.setTimer(); // setup timeout on mount

  componentWillUnmount = () => this.clearTimer(); // remove timeout in case of component unmount

  clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(this.timeout); // clear timeout

  timer = () => this.setState({ showChild: false }, () => this.clearTimer()); // update state and clear timeout

  setTimer = () => (this.timeout = setTimeout(this.timer, 5000)); // setup a 5s timeout

  render = () => <div>{this.state.showChild && <Example />}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import App from './App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('initially renders a child component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.child')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('removes child component after a 5 second timeout', () => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);
    expect(wrapper.find('.child')).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});
```